# How to change target based on link type in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="displayPIHomeLinks" match="/">
        <div class="justPad">
            <xsl:for-each select="Collection/Content">
                <div class="brClear percPadTop">
                    <a class="defaultLinks" target="_blank">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/lnkAttach/a/@href" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/txtTitle" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue I am having is some `href` are PDF which I want it to open in new window while others are ASPX which I would want to open in the same window.

Please help me accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to output the `a` so that inclusion of `@target` is conditional upon the suffix of the `@href`:

```
<xsl:variable name="href" select="Html/root/lnkAttach/a/@href"/>
<xsl:variable name="pdf_suffix" select="'.pdf'"/>
<a class="defaultLinks">
    <xsl:if test="$pdf_suffix = 
                  substring($href, string-length($href) - string-length($pdf_suffix)+1)">
      <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$href"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/txtTitle"/>
</a>
```

Note that the `substring()` construct is an XPath 1.0 way of doing `ends-with()` without XPath 2.0.

Comment: I have to use `1.0` so I had to accept your answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

When using XSLT 2.0, you can use `ends-with()` to check if the href value ends with pdf and add `target="'_blank'"`, example XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
       omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template  match="lnkAttach">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
      <a class="defaultLinks" >
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="ends-with(@href, 'pdf')">
           <xsl:attribute name="target" select="'_blank'"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
       </a>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this example XML:

```
<lnkAttach>
  <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
  <a href="www.w3.org/People/maxf/XSLideMaker/tut.pdf">W3C XSL</a>
  <a href="www.thedailywtf.com">Daily</a>
</lnkAttach>
```

following output is produced:

```
  <a class="defaultLinks" href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
  <a class="defaultLinks" href="www.w3.org/People/maxf/XSLideMaker/tut.pdf"
    target="_blank">W3C XSL</a>
  <a class="defaultLinks" href="www.thedailywtf.com">Daily</a>
```

In case it's possible that the PDF link doesn't end with PDF, but has some additional parameters, you can use `contains()` instead, e.g. like `<xsl:if test="contains(@href, '.pdf')">` (just added a `.` for the case a link target contains `pdf` without having the extension).

**Update:** Just updated my answer (adjusted to XSLT 2.0) as I just noticed that the online XSLT Processor I used for testing didn't threw an error though I used `ends-with()` in an XSLT declared as version 1.0. For an XSLT 1.0 solution kjhughes answer is the correct way to check if the href ends with .pdf, or you can use `contains()` as suggested.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Glad if I was able to help, but just updated my answer as I just noticed - thanks to kjhughes answer - that I used the wrong XSLT version.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use `1.0` to which @kjhughes answers works perfectly. I did +1 your answer for the response. If someone uses `2.0` this works fine as well. Thank you :)